# How to properly format and section an image to be on the right side of text with HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, image, formatting

I am trying to make it so the webpage displays five images that are properly formatted to be on the right side of its corresponding text. Each sub-section (facial, skin solution, lashes, microblading, and eyebrow) should be arranged relative to the title, text, and image.

This is how the the webpage is looking so far. [image]

What is the best way to correct this?
Here is the code for context.

**HTML**

```
    <!--Features-->
    <section id="feature">
    <div class="title-text">
    <p>SERVICES</p>
    <h1>Why Choose Us</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-box">   
        <div class="features">
            <h1>Facials</h1>
            <div class="feature-desc">
                <div class="feature-text">
                    <div class="feature-pics"> <!-- -->
                    <img id="facial-pic" src="images/facials.PNG">
                    </div>
                    <p>Custom Facials<br>
                        Custom Chemical Peel Facials<br>
                        Image O2 Lift Facial<br>
                        Galvanic Facial<br>
                        Circadia Oxygen RX Facial<br>
                        Dermaplaning Facial<br>
                        Microdermabrasion Facial<br>
                        Microneeding Facial<br>
                        Fox C Peel Facial<br>
                        Plamere Skin Tightening Facial<br>
                        Plasma Fusion Facial<br>
                        FCR Facial<br></p>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <h1>Skin Care Solutions</h1>
            <div class="feature-desc">
                <div class="feature-text">
                    <div class="feature-pics"> <!-- -->
                    <img id="skin-solution-pic" src="images/skin_solutions.PNG">
                    </div>
                    <p>Skin Tags<br>
                        Cherry Angiomas<br>
                        Sebacious Hyperplasia<br>
                        Fibromas<br>
                        Seborrheic Keratosis<br>
                        Flat Hyperigmentation<br>
                        Acne Lesions<br>
                        Milias<br>
                        Closed Comedones<br>
                        Cappillaries<br>
                    </p>
                </div>  
            </div>  

            <h1>Custom Lashes</h1>
            <div class="feature-desc">
                <div class="feature-text">
                    <div class="feature-pics"> <!-- -->
                    <img id="custom-lash-pic" src="images/lash.PNG">
                    </div>
                    <p>Full Set of Classic and Volume Lash Extension<br>
                        Lash Extension Fill<br>
                        Lash Extension Removal<br>
                        Lash Lift and Tint<br>
                    </p>
                </div>  
            </div> 

            <h1>Microblading</h1>
            <div class="feature-desc">
                <div class="feature-text">
                    <div class="feature-pics"> <!-- -->
                    <img id="microblading-pic" src="images/microblading.PNG">
                    </div>
                    <p>Permanent Eyebrow Tattoo Techinque<br>
                    </p>
                </div>  
            </div> 

            <h1>Eyebrow Treatment</h1>
            <div class="feature-desc">
                <div class="feature-text">
                    <div class="feature-pics"> <!-- -->
                    <img id="eyebrow-pic" src="images/eyebrow_treatment.PNG">
                    </div>
                    <p>Eyebrow Waxing<br>
                        Eyebrow Tint<br>
                </p>
                </div>  
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

**CSS**

```
#feature{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 60px 0px;
}
.title-text{
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}
.title-text p{
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #009688;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}
.title-text p::after{ /*creates the leaf effect layered on top of the title text*/
    content:'';
    width: 50px;
    height: 35px;
    background: linear-gradient(#34eb98, #fff);
    position: absolute;
    top: -20;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
    border-top-left-radius: 35px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 35px;
}
.title-text h1{
    font-size: 50px;
}
.feature-box{
    width: 60%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.features{
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
.features h1{
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 2.5px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #009688;
}
.features-desc{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    display: flex;
}
.feature-text p{
    padding: 0 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: initial;
}
.feature-pics{
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `float: right;` from `.feature-pics`. Put the all `.feature-pics` after the `p` tag (html structure), as in my example. And add this rule to your css:

```
.feature-text {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```css
#feature{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 60px 0px;
}
.title-text{
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}
.title-text p{
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #009688;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}
.title-text p::after{ /*creates the leaf effect layered on top of the title text*/
    content:'';
    width: 50px;
    height: 35px;
    background: linear-gradient(#34eb98, #fff);
    position: absolute;
    top: -20;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
    border-top-left-radius: 35px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 35px;
}
.title-text h1{
    font-size: 50px;
}
.feature-box{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -30px;
}
.features{
    flex-basis: 50%;
}
.features-img{
    flex-basis: 50%;
    margin: auto;
}
.features-img img{
    width: 70%;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.features h1{
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 2.5px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #009688;
}
.features-desc{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    display: flex;
}

.feature-text {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.feature-text p{
    padding: 0 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: initial;
}
.feature-pics{
    width: 200px;
    /*float: right;*/
}

.feature-pics img{
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!--Features-->
    <section id="feature">
    <div class="title-text">
    <p>SERVICES</p>
    <h1>Why Choose Us</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="feature-box">   
        <div class="features">
            <h1>Facials</h1>
            <div class="feature-desc">
                <div class="feature-text">
                    
                    <p>Custom Facials<br>
                        Custom Chemical Peel Facials<br>
                        Image O2 Lift Facial<br>
                        Galvanic Facial<br>
                        Circadia Oxygen RX Facial<br>
                        Dermaplaning Facial<br>
                        Microdermabrasion Facial<br>
                        Microneeding Facial<br>
                        Fox C Peel Facial<br>
                        Plamere Skin Tightening Facial<br>
                        Plasma Fusion Facial<br>
                        FCR Facial<br></p>
                        <div class="feature-pics"> <!-- -->
                    <img id="facial-pic" src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/450/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <h1>Skin Care Solutions</h1>
            <div class="feature-desc">
                <div class="feature-text">
                    
                    <p>Skin Tags<br>
                        Cherry Angiomas<br>
                        Sebacious Hyperplasia<br>
                        Fibromas<br>
                        Seborrheic Keratosis<br>
                        Flat Hyperigmentation<br>
                        Acne Lesions<br>
                        Milias<br>
                        Closed Comedones<br>
                        Cappillaries<br>
                    </p>
                    <div class="feature-pics"> <!-- -->
                    <img id="skin-solution-pic" src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/450/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>  

            <h1>Custom Lashes</h1>
            <div class="feature-desc">
                <div class="feature-text">
                    
                    <p>Full Set of Classic and Volume Lash Extension<br>
                        Lash Extension Fill<br>
                        Lash Extension Removal<br>
                        Lash Lift and Tint<br>
                    </p>
                    
                    <div class="feature-pics"> <!-- -->
                    <img id="custom-lash-pic" src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/450/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div> 

            <h1>Microblading</h1>
            <div class="feature-desc">
                <div class="feature-text">
                    
                    <p>Permanent Eyebrow Tattoo Techinque<br>
                    </p>
                    <div class="feature-pics"> <!-- -->
                    <img id="microblading-pic" src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/450/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div> 

            <h1>Eyebrow Treatment</h1>
            <div class="feature-desc">
                <div class="feature-text">
                    
                    <p>Eyebrow Waxing<br>
                        Eyebrow Tint<br>
                </p>
                <div class="feature-pics"> <!-- -->
                    <img id="eyebrow-pic" src="https://static3.depositphotos.com/1000992/133/i/450/depositphotos_1337508-stock-photo-a-free-flying-white-dove.jpg">
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions and it fixed the formatting when viewing the webpage on a browser. However, when viewing the webpage from a mobile perspective it causes the homepage to be cut off on the right side. Any suggestion on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will solve your problem. Just a few things I added a url image to test your code so you'll need to change it back. What I did was gave the same id to each one of your images and then adjusted the CSS. Next I enclosed each one of your sections (which includes the image) inside a div and gave a the same class name to each div. From there I adjusted the width and height of that div so that all of your images were positioned appropriately.

Here is a codepen https://codepen.io/mikejact/pen/xxOWmGY

and....

See code below:

HTML:

```
   <!--Features-->
<section id="feature">
<div class="title-text">
<p>SERVICES</p>
<h1>Why Choose Us</h1>
</div>
<div class="feature-box">   
    <div class="features">
        <h1>Facials</h1>
        <div class="feature-desc">
            <div class="feature-text">
                <div class="feature-pics"> <!-- -->
                <img id="facial-pic" src="https://c.files.bbci.co.uk/12A9B/production/_111434467_gettyimages-1143489763.jpg">
                </div>
              <div class = "sample">
                <p>Custom Facials<br>
                    Custom Chemical Peel Facials<br>
                    Image O2 Lift Facial<br>
                    Galvanic Facial<br>
                    Circadia Oxygen RX Facial<br>
                    Dermaplaning Facial<br>
                    Microdermabrasion Facial<br>
                    Microneeding Facial<br>
                    Fox C Peel Facial<br>
                    Plamere Skin Tightening Facial<br>
                    Plasma Fusion Facial<br>
                    FCR Facial<br></p>
              </div>
            </div>  
        </div>
      <div class = "sample">
        <h1>Skin Care Solutions</h1>
        <div class="feature-desc">
            <div class="feature-text">
                <div class="feature-pics"> <!-- -->
                <img id="facial-pic" src="https://c.files.bbci.co.uk/12A9B/production/_111434467_gettyimages-1143489763.jpg">
                </div>
                <p>Skin Tags<br>
                    Cherry Angiomas<br>
                    Sebacious Hyperplasia<br>
                    Fibromas<br>
                    Seborrheic Keratosis<br>
                    Flat Hyperigmentation<br>
                    Acne Lesions<br>
                    Milias<br>
                    Closed Comedones<br>
                    Cappillaries<br>
                </p>
            </div>  
        </div>  
      </div>
      <div class = "sample">
        <h1>Custom Lashes</h1>
        <div class="feature-desc">
            <div class="feature-text">
                <div class="feature-pics"> <!-- -->
                <img id="facial-pic" src="https://c.files.bbci.co.uk/12A9B/production/_111434467_gettyimages-1143489763.jpg">
                </div>
                <p>Full Set of Classic and Volume Lash Extension<br>
                    Lash Extension Fill<br>
                    Lash Extension Removal<br>
                    Lash Lift and Tint<br>
                </p>
            </div>  
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class = "sample">
        <h1>Microblading</h1>
        <div class="feature-desc">
            <div class="feature-text">
                <div class="feature-pics"> <!-- -->
                <img id="facial-pic" src="https://c.files.bbci.co.uk/12A9B/production/_111434467_gettyimages-1143489763.jpg">
                </div>
                <p>Permanent Eyebrow Tattoo Techinque<br>
                </p>
            </div>  
        </div> 
      </div>
      <div class = "sample">
        <h1>Eyebrow Treatment</h1>
        <div class="feature-desc">
            <div class="feature-text">
                <div class="feature-pics"> <!-- -->
                <img id="facial-pic" src="https://c.files.bbci.co.uk/12A9B/production/_111434467_gettyimages-1143489763.jpg">
                </div>
                <p>Eyebrow Waxing<br>
                    Eyebrow Tint<br>
            </p>
            </div>  
        </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
   #feature{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 60px 0px;
}

#facial-pic{
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  float: right;
}
.title-text{
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 70px;
}
.title-text p{
    margin: auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #009688;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
}
.title-text p::after{ /*creates the leaf effect layered on top of the title text*/
    content:'';
    width: 50px;
    height: 35px;
    background: linear-gradient(#34eb98, #fff);
    position: absolute;
    top: -20;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    transform: rotate(10deg);
    border-top-left-radius: 35px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 35px;
}
.title-text h1{
    font-size: 50px;
}
.feature-box{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -30px;
}

.features h1{
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: 2.5px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #009688;
}
.features-desc{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    display: flex;
}
.feature-text p{
    padding: 0 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: initial;
}


.sample {
 width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
}
```